# I need a way of receiving data regularly even when app is minimized?

Tags: android, mysql

I'm building an app that currently can receive data from an SQL database through the click of a button.
How can I automate the app (so I don't need the button) so it receives the data constantly (or every x seconds I don't mind) and then sends a notification to the user if certain data has come through. I need the data receiving and checking to be done even when the app is minimized/not on the user's screen. I've heard talk of using 'services' but i'm relatively new to app dev so no idea on the matter.

Any help appreciated,

Cheers.

Comment: "How can I automate the app (so I don't need the button) so it receives the data constantly (or every x seconds I don't mind) and then sends a notification to the user if certain data has come through" -- you cannot do anything that quickly, particularly on Android 6.0+, due to battery drain. You need to rethink your approach to be in line with what will work for users (e.g., updates every hour, using FCM-style push messages to avoid polling). "i'm relatively new to app dev so no idea on the matter" -- you may wish to consider reading a book or taking a course on Android app development.

Comment: I think you must read about PendingIntent, AlarmManager, JobScheduler, Service. A lot of work to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to android programming is a bit complex but you can implement this functionality using:
- Services: sends request to the server every x seconds(manually)
-Sync Adapter: (you need to know services ) android mechanism for doing exactly what you want.

More at: https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

EDIT: you could also use firebase to send push notification